# Import css file vs. createGlobalStyle

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components

What is the purpose of using createGlobalStyle instead of just importing a css file, when working with styled components?

I have read the docs, but i don't get it..

Comment: you can use the theme properties with `createGlobalStyle`